# Predictions using glmnet in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to model some data using the `glmnet` package in R. Let's say I have the following data

```
training_x <- data.frame(variable1 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3),
                         variable2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

(This is a simplification; my data are much more complicated.) Then I used the following code to create the glmnet model.

```
x <- as.matrix(training_x)
library(glmnet)
GLMnet_model_1 <- glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian", alpha=0.755,
                         nlambda=1000, standardize=FALSE, maxit=100000)
```

I am using `standardize=FALSE` because my real life data are already standardized. Then I want to make prediction over a new set of data. Let's say my new data are:

```
newdata <- as.matrix(data.frame(variable1 = c(2, 2, 1, 3), 
                                variable2 = c(6, 2, 1, 3)))
results <- predict(object=GLMnet_model_1, newx, type="response")
```

I would expect results to contain 4 elements (predictions of the `newdata`), but instead it gives me a 4x398 matrix. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify for which value of lambda you want to predict the response. All you need to do is to call like like e.g.:

```
results <-predict(GLMnet_model_1, s=0.01, newx, type="response")
```